# Parallax fade without jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

I am trying to make a website with a parallax scrolling. I have the basic code but I want the images to fade out when I scroll down to to the next image and fade in when it comes on screen. I am using pure HTML and CSS, no plugins. How should I do this? Here is my code:

```css
#divname {
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1024/600/abstract/');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
    width: 100vw;
 height: auto;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}

.text {
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

.header {
 font-size: 10vw;
}
```

```html
  <div id="divname">
                <div class="text">
    <p class="header">Headername</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc facilisis dictum mi ac euismod. Aenean fermentum nisl ut lorem cursus, in consectetur est eleifend.</p>
   </div>
          <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

PS: By the way, I am fine with using javascript, but I would rather not use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what do you want,
But you need to **separate** your Images from the other texts, Otherwise all your `#divaname` will fade out when scrolling.

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById('divname');

function scrolled() {
    
    if (window.pageYOffset < 100) {
        myDiv.style.opacity = 1;
    } else {
        myDiv.style.opacity = 0.3;
    }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', scrolled);
```

```css
#divname {
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1024/600/abstract/');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
    width: 100vw;
 height: auto;
 background-attachment: fixed;
    transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.text {
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

.header {
 font-size: 10vw;
}
```

```html
    <div id="divname">
                <div class="text">
    <p class="header">Headername</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc facilisis dictum mi ac euismod. Aenean fermentum nisl ut lorem cursus, in consectetur est eleifend.</p>
   </div>
          <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to make it fade in fully only when it's all the way on the screen without having to do trial and error to find the correct y offset?

Comment: You need to do trail and error every time you scroll to check your current Y Offset, Otherwise it will stay fade out even If you get back to top. If you want that Just remove the `else` condition.